# How to make vertical (front and back) movement of a player in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I'm building a game project in Unity 3D, I managed to make player move left or right but facing problem in making the player move front and back.

It is the part of the code. What to do to make player move front and back? I have used the getaxis function, but still not working.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            jump = true;
        }
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); ;
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput, GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y, 0);
        

        if (jump==true)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * 5, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```csharp
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput, GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y, verticalInput);
    if (jump==true)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * 5, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        jump = false;
    }
}
```

If you instead of setting the z-axis of the velocity vector to zero, you set it to the value of the verticalInput this will allow the player to move forward and backward based on the value of the "Vertical" axis.